# Apache Flink ListState<String> vs ValueState<List<String>>

Tags: java, apache-flink

Looking at the documentation, it seems like I could use either a `ListState` or a `ValueState<List<String>>` to store state. For example the code below:

```
// Use ListState
ListStateDescriptor<String> lDescriptor = new ListStateDescriptor<String> 
     ("testListState", TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<String>() {}));

ListState<String> testListState = getRuntimeContext().getListState(lDescriptor);


// Use ValueState
ValueStateDescriptor<List<String>> testDescriptor =
 new ValueStateDescriptor<List<String>>("testList",
 TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<List<String>>() {}));

ValueState<List<String>> testState = getRuntimeContext().getState(testDescriptor);
```

If I need to store a unique list of elements tied to each key, would there be a benefit of using one over the other? The downside of using ListState would be first converting the Iterable to a List<> if I need to modify it before saving the list whereas I could just retrieve the list directly if I use ValueState.

Comment: ValueState<List<String>> may have race conditions

Answer (score 2):

I only use *ValueState* if I only want store one value to each key. You can use it to store lists, but the code will be more verbose.
If you use *ValueState*, you must get the value, update the list, and update the value but if you use *ListState* you can manage it directly

Comment: I agree. The only reason to use ValueState here is if you wanted a specific collection type (like Set) rather than a list.

Comment: What about the performance aspect of using ValueState vs ListState?